# Copy files from remote machine to folder on remote machine

Tags: linux, cp, remote

Why do we get the following error about "No such file or directory" when we copy files from remote folder to another remote folder?

```
 ssh -n -o  ConnectTimeout=50 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -xaq  $IP "cp -rp /opt/dir  /tmp"


 cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/dir/edits_inprogress_0000000001294909743’: No such file or directory
```

... or maybe there is a better approach?

we also try

```
 find  /opt/dir  -print0 | rsync -0a --files-from=- --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir /tmp/
rsync: --ignore-missing-args: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1435) [client=3.0.9]



rsync --version
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
Copyright (C) 1996-2011 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

Comment: It seems some program is creating temporary files that are deleted in-between `cp` detecting they're there and actually copying them.

Comment: so in that case how we can ignore it? ( the  temporary files situation )

Comment: do you know option in cp that ignore deleted files ?

Comment: @Yael I agree this is a stupid error: `Can not make file not exist, because it does not exist.` Just take a bow, and walk off the stage.

Comment: @yael Try with `cd /opt/dir && find . -print0 | rsync -0a --files-from=- --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir /tmp`, which is equivalent to your `cp -rp` command except that if any "volatile" file exists at `find` time but not at `rsync` time, `rsync` should ignore it. I guess race conditions might still occur while `rsync` is operating, but perhaps this way is more forgiving than a recursive `cp`

Comment: can I just do - find /opt/dir -print0 | rsync -0a --files-from=- --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir /tmp

Comment: see my update in the quastion

Comment: @yael no `rsync --files-from` wants relative paths, whilst `find /opt/dir` would produce paths comprising `/opt/dir/..` hence you'd end up having `/tmp/opt/dir/...`. Anyways you must have a pretty old `rsync` there, if it doesn't know `--ignore-missing-args` option.

Comment: so in that case , we have old rsync , what are the other options?

Comment: Not that it will solve the issue at hand, but that version of `rsync` is very old. The current version is 3.1.3. If you are using a system that hasn't been updated since between 2011 and 2013, it's high time to do that update now, just to patch the numerous security issues that have been fixed over the years (not just in `rsync`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just you can try with rsync command for this

For local host sync you can use below command

```
rsync -avzh /home/praveen/10 /var/tmp/
```

For syncing with remote machines

```
rsync -avzh remotemachineip:/remotemachineath localserverdestinationfolder
```

Comment: Don't these two solutions copy files locally-to-locally and remotely-to-locally? The question is about copying "files from remote folder to other remote folder"