# rsync + using the flag ignore-missing-args

Tags: linux, find, rsync

I am using the rsync version - 3.1.2.0

```
/usr/bin/rsync_bpc --version
rsync_bpc  version 3.1.2.0  protocol version 31
```

in order to copy files from `/opt/dir to /tmp`

I am also using the flag- `--ignore-missing-args`   in order to ignore missing source args without error

```
cd /opt/dir
find . -print0 | /usr/bin/rsync_bpc -0a --files-from=- --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir  /tmp
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(1859) [client=3.1.2.0]
```

what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Not an answer, but why are you piping from `find` if you want to sync _everything_? Can't you just use `.` as the source directory with `rsync` directly?  Also, if you read from the pipe, what is your intention with the two pathnames at the end of the command?

Comment: please see the previous note  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531291/copy-files-from-remote-machine-to-folder-on-remote-machine  ( from LL3 )

Comment: Yeah, that comment is probably getting the command slightly wrong. I'm on my way to a bus but may look at this again later if nobody else steps in first.  It's a matter of dropping the `cd`, `find` and `--files-from`.

Comment: ok > I will wait for you answer

Comment: @Kusalananda and @yael, my point there is that without `--files-from` it should be no different than what `cp -r` does, whereas feeding `rsync` with a pre-built list is an attempt to best the race condition problem. This is because `--ignore-missing-args` applies only to command arguments (like in `rsync *.sh /tmp`) and to `--files-from`, not to the list `rsync` computes internally during its `-a` (or `-r`) recursive operation. At least this is what I get from man-page and from a quick look at `rsync` sources, the `extern int missing_args` and its use only in the `send_file_list` function

Comment: .. well, naturally `missing_args` is not used *only* there, but there is where seems to be only relevant for the race-condition problem case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't reproduce the error that you are getting, your pipeline for copying the directory structure rooted in `/opt/dir` to `/tmp` is needlessly complicated.

The copying could be done with just

```
rsync -a --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir /tmp
```

This would create `/tmp/dir` with the full contents of `/opt/dir`, and no `cd` or `find` is necessary.

---

Thinking a bit more about it, the error *could* come from the fact that you are seemingly using a separately compiled binary called `rsync_bpc`.  The `rsync_bpc` binary will execute `rsync` for the sender and for the receiver of the copy operation (even for local copying).  If `rsync` on your system does not support `--ignore-missing-args` (remembering your [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531291), you have a *very old* `rsync`), you may have to tell `rsync_bpc` to use `rsync_bpc` instead of `rsync`.

You do that with the `--rsync-path` option:

```
/usr/bin/rsync_bpc --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync_bpc -a --ignore-missing-args /opt/dir /tmp
```